# how do GROUP_CONCAT grouped by profile of subquery?

Tags: sql, subquery, group-concat

i need create a GROUP_CONCAT grouped by profile_id but when i add GROUP_CONCAT to select, the result only show one record, i need concatenate the string associated by profile_id

Like:

One:Value1, Two:Value2

my query do this:

Image: https://prnt.sc/p4jpx9

My Query:

```sql
SELECT 
    perfiles.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.asignados) AS asignado
FROM
    perfiles
LEFT JOIN (

    SELECT
        niveles_asignacion_perfiles.id_perfil AS id_perfil_asignacion,
        CONCAT(rec.nombrePadre, ":", rec.nombreValor) AS asignados
    FROM
        niveles_asignacion_perfiles
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT catalogo_niveles_valores.id AS valorID,
            catalogo_niveles.nivel_code AS orden,
            catalogo_niveles.nombre AS nombrePadre,
            catalogo_niveles_valores.nombre AS nombreValor
        FROM
            catalogo_niveles_valores
        LEFT JOIN catalogo_niveles ON catalogo_niveles.id_nivel = catalogo_niveles_valores.id_catalogo_nivel
    ) AS rec
    ON
        rec.valorID = niveles_asignacion_perfiles.id_asignacion
    ORDER BY
        rec.orden ASC   

) as t ON t.id_perfil_asignacion = perfiles.id_perfil
```

```sql
    SELECT
        niveles_asignacion_perfiles.id_perfil AS id_perfil_asignacion,
        CONCAT(rec.nombrePadre, ":", rec.nombreValor) AS asignados
    FROM
        niveles_asignacion_perfiles
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT catalogo_niveles_valores.id AS valorID,
            catalogo_niveles.nivel_code AS orden,
            catalogo_niveles.nombre AS nombrePadre,
            catalogo_niveles_valores.nombre AS nombreValor
        FROM
            catalogo_niveles_valores
        LEFT JOIN catalogo_niveles ON catalogo_niveles.id_nivel = catalogo_niveles_valores.id_catalogo_nivel
    ) AS rec
    ON
        rec.valorID = niveles_asignacion_perfiles.id_asignacion
    ORDER BY
        rec.orden ASC
```

i need do groups with id_profile, group_concat() with my data asociated but all strings be concatenated to first result and not show all profiles..

Comment: Tag appropriate database name, add sample data and add what your expected output from the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with group by:

```
SELECT
    niveles_asignacion_perfiles.id_perfil AS id_perfil_asignacion,
    CONCAT(
        rec.nombrePadre,
        ":",
        rec.nombreValor
    ) AS asignados
FROM
    niveles_asignacion_perfiles
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        catalogo_niveles_valores.id AS valorID,
        catalogo_niveles.nivel_code AS orden,
        catalogo_niveles.nombre AS nombrePadre,
        catalogo_niveles_valores.nombre AS nombreValor
    FROM
        catalogo_niveles_valores
    LEFT JOIN catalogo_niveles ON catalogo_niveles.id_nivel = catalogo_niveles_valores.id_catalogo_nivel
) AS rec
ON
    rec.valorID = niveles_asignacion_perfiles.id_asignacion
ORDER BY
    rec.orden ASC
`` `
```